# Error importing files from index file after React native update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a common structure to export/import my screens from an index file like this;

```
export { default as HomePage } from './HomePage/Home';
export { default as LandingPage } from './LandingPage/Landing';
```

It was working fine until I update react native from 0.65 to 0.67.4  .

It says "Cannot read property 'HomePage' of undefined". it's like it can't see the index file at all. Remember this was all working fine so I think it's a syntax error or anything minor like that. I've tired to clear watchman and reset cache. Nothing worked.

exact error that I got:

[image]

Comment: hey @İlker, did you figure this out?

Comment: I have the same issue